Suggestions for analyzing synchronization data and running a two-factor ANOVA on circular data on MATLAB
I am running a tapping experiment where I have to analyze whether meter and/or pattern affect the synchronization performance. The within subjects experiment is comprised of 6 conditions, so it's a 2 x3 experiment (meter x pattern).
Basically what I have is the tapping timing of the participants, which I compare to the timing of the note onsets. The results I get are the phase lag and PLV for each trial.
% Match each tap to the closest note onset
closest_note_indices = arrayfun(@(x) find(abs(notetiming - x) == min(abs(notetiming - x)), 1), taptimestamp);
closest_notes = notetiming(closest_note_indices);

% Calculate phase lag
phase_lag = angle(exp(1i * 2 * pi * (taptimestamp - closest_notes) ./ mean(diff(notetiming))));
phase_lags = [phase_lags; mean(phase_lag)];

% Calculate PLV
plv = abs(mean(exp(1i * phase_lag)));
plv_values = [plv_values; plv];

At the group level, I averaged all the trials of each participant so now I have their aggregated data.
% Aggregate data: Average each participant's data for each 
combination of meter and pattern 
aggData = varfun(@mean, dataTable, 'GroupingVariables', 
{'ParticipantID', 'Meter', 'Pattern'}, ...
    'InputVariables', {'PhaseLag', 'PLV', 'TapRatio', 
'TapError', 'TapAccuracy'});

Now, I need to find a way to run a two-factor ANOVA on matlab. The thing is, I don't have experience with running this kind of analysis on circular data and I know it requires a special kind of procedure. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can proceed?
So far I've got this code to prepare the data for the Harrison-Kanji test:
% Reorganize the data for the two-factor within-subjects ANOVA
nParticipants = numel(unique(aggData.ParticipantID));
meters = unique(aggData.Meter);
patterns = unique(aggData.Pattern);
nMeters = numel(meters);
nPatterns = numel(patterns);

phaseLagData = NaN(nParticipants, nMeters, nPatterns);
plvData = NaN(nParticipants, nMeters, nPatterns);

for i = 1:nParticipants
 for j = 1:nMeters
     for k = 1:nPatterns
         idx = aggData.ParticipantID == i & 
  strcmp(aggData.Meter, 
  meters{j}) & strcmp(aggData.Pattern, patterns{k});
        if any(idx)
            phaseLagData(i, j, k) = 
 aggData.circ_mean_PhaseLag(idx);
            plvData(i, j, k) = aggData.circ_mean_PLV(idx);
             end
         end
     end
 end

% Convert to radians for circular statistics
phaseLagData = deg2rad(phaseLagData);
plvData = deg2rad(plvData);

I have tried to run a Harrison-Kanji test but my output always results in NaN values for the p-values, which is strange cause the data appears to be valid (no missing data, consistent amount of data points per group). So I am getting something like this:
Angles for PhaseLag (in degrees): 0.1872    -0.12609    -0.26187    -0.15538     0.13689       0.426   -0.034659     0.23428   -0.031413     0.23462
Angles for PLV (in degrees): 0.14884    0.062623     0.22645     0.14601     0.12632     0.32505    0.077925     0.13987    0.077551    0.087998
P-value for PhaseLag (Meter: 7/8, Pattern: reverse): NaN
P-value for PhaseLag (Meter: NaN, Pattern: NaN): P-value for PLV (Meter: 7/8, Pattern: reverse): NaN
P-value for PLV (Meter: NaN, Pattern: NaN): P-values for PhaseLag:
    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}
    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}

P-values for PLV:
    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}
    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}    {[NaN NaN NaN]}

So far this is what my code tries to do:
Load data
Convert to table
Compute Radial Fields
Assign group IDs: Assign unique group IDs based on the combination of ParticipantID, Meter, and Pattern
Specific Condition Analysis: Filter data based on specific conditions and compute angles and p-values.
I'm just so stuck on the ANOVA stage, if anyone could give me any suggestions I would be so grateful.

please add more code and simplify the initial explanation so readers can reproduce errors. As it is now, readers are clueless at how you get the few lines shown in your question : more code

@JohnBofarullGuix ok! I've just added more details. Hopefully it's a little bit clearer :)
